How to send preformatted commands as strings to redis using hiredis
I'm sending the prepared commands to redis as a string,strings containing space characters are being added as separate key-value parts. I'm using the fmt library to format the strings and then sending them to Redis.
std::string text = "canceled by user";
auto cmd = fmt::format("HSET xxx text '{}'", text);
auto reply = redisCommand(ctx, cmd.c_str());

When I input this code, the output in Redis-CLI appears as follows:
127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall xxx
1) "text"
2) "'canceled"
3) "by"
4) "user'"

In this case, how can I send strings prepared externally to hiredis? If I use Redis's own formatting, there is no problem at all, like:
auto reply = redisCommand(ctx, "HSET xxx test %s", text.c_str());

This works correctly, but I don't want to use it this way. I want to prepare all the commands myself and provide them as strings.
